# Apache rewrite 1 file globally to new file URL

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a file with an identical name that exists in 15 subdirectories. Let's say it's called `blah.txt`.

I'm looking to do a global rewrite within `httpd.conf` to match any subdirectory's `blah.txt` and Rewrite it to a singular `http://myserver/blah.txt`.

If I add the following to an `.htaccess`, it works great. I hit the subdirectory's txt file, and I'm 301 forwarded. However doing this means I need to manage 15 .htaccess's. I'm trying to avoid that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blah)\.txt http://myserver/blah.txt [L,R=301]
```

If I put this same text into httpd.conf under the `<Directory />` section, I get a 404 on the subdirectory's `blah.txt`.

```
<Directory />
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(blah)\.txt http://myserver/blah.txt [L,R=301]


</Directory>
```

How can I have this global match within `httpd.conf`?

**Edit:** If I change the `httpd.conf` rewrite to the below, it seems like it *wants* to work, however I get stuck in an infinite loop because it's constantly matching the same file name.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule blah.txt http://myserver/blah.txt [L,R=301]
```

Still looking for a way to have it match in subdirectories and redirect to the same filename.

**Edit 2:** I think I got this working - but would love confirmation!

I added a `RewriteCond` to my rule. Basically, I think, this means that if the URI does not contain "firmware", then rewrite.

```
<Directory />
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(firmware) [NC]
    RewriteRule blah.txt firmware/series/version/blah.txt [R=301,L]

</Directory>
```

It seems to be working without looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my **Edit 2:** I think I got this working.

I added a `RewriteCond` to my rule. Basically, I think, this means that if the URI does not contain "firmware", then rewrite.

```
<Directory />
    Options All Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(firmware) [NC]
    RewriteRule blah.txt firmware/series/version/blah.txt [R=301,L]

</Directory>
```

After quite a bit of testing, it seems to be working without looping